# Python import module from nearby directory instead of from site packages

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to test changes to a Python module, let's call it `my_import_module`.  Currently, it's in a site package.  I would like to import it from my local file structure, not from my site packages.

The folder structure looks like this:

```
dir
|--dirA
   |--dirB
      |--my_import_file.py
      |--__init__.py
|--dirC
   |--dirD
      |--main.py
      |--__init__.py
```

I am trying to import the file `my_import_file.py` into `main.py`, and not from the site packages version.

Currently I have `from ../../dirA.dirB.my_import_file import XYZ`.  This doesn't work.

I would like to not add `__init__.py` into each directory.

Two questions:

- How can I import `my_import_file.py` from the directory instead of from site packages?
- What is the Python code to import `my_import_file`?

Comment: Stop thinking about files and directories and start thinking about packages and modules. Then decide in which package you want the module to be (i.e. is it `import dirA.dirB.my_import_file`, or just `import my_import_file`). Then organise the directories the way you want packages to be structured and put an `__init__.py` into each package, because that is how packages are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/

The way to do is

```
from ...dirA.dirB.my_import_file import XYZ
```